# Space issue in ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, linux-kernel, docker

I am new to the linux environment,

```
root@environment-7:~# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             4044556        0   4044556   0% /dev
tmpfs             812572    80328    732244  10% /run
/dev/sdb1       30309264 30292880         0 100% /
tmpfs            4062840        0   4062840   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            4062840        0   4062840   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb15        106858     3668    103190   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       16447292    45448  15546656   1% /mnt
tmpfs             812568        0    812568   0% /run/user/1001
tmpfs             812568        0    812568   0% /run/user/1000
overlay         30309264 30292880         0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/70e69c1133c316ce3bc808d9389f3150ec4c192240f9242235842177289b2ae0/merged
shm                65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e7aaed36b6147e9ef9ce8670729402a45c7f3a4897117278571db703e461c81f/mounts/shm
overlay         30309264 30292880         0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/cb33eeabab21d52cb7a5231ea39a4d4d5c08c70703e49eb469a10850713018ec/merged
overlay         30309264 30292880         0 100% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/9fb1d30f33561342c2f4cc5e963730016d19c745e58619c85257ed250032f23f/merged
shm                65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/cf470959b656e2269f9cd55638d22a8b96cf20de4408765f019bec0181cf4f3e/mounts/shm
shm                65536        0     65536   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/9e86ecee9b0b7ae8db26fa326d6e3278387f815806c8cd625382a20255134f69/mounts/shm
```

I deployed 3 application installed in docker and when I try to login to one of the docker,
I get the following error,

```
docker exec -it e7a bash
```

**failed to create runc console socket: mkdir /tmp/pty976898784: no space left on device: unknown**

Could someone explain this error please?

Even when I try /dev/ and click on tab, It is throwing the following error

**cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device**

Anyhelp is appreciated.

Thanks,
Harry

Comment: As the error message says you're out of space, your disk is full. You need to increase your /dev/sdb1 partition since that is where your docker containers are running.

Comment: Look at the 4th line of the `df` output you show, it tells you that `/dev/sdb1`, which is your root partition (`/`), the equivalent of `C:\` in the Windows world, is 100% full.

Comment: @eblock thanks for the quick response, How did you say the docker depends on the /dev/sdb1 folder?

Comment: @eblock Awesome Thanks, You can post this as answer If you have time. I will it. Before that what is the difference between /var/lib/docker/overlay2/ and /var/lib/docker/containers ?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with docker, maybe someone else can describe that better, but AFAIU the containers are stored within `/var/lib/docker/containers` and then mounted as an overlay filesystem within `/var/lib/docker/overlay`. But this may be wrong, I'm currently gathering first experiences with containers.

Comment: you might try `docker container prune` and `docker image prune` to free no longer needed container and images.

Answer (score 0):

`/var` is mounted underneath `/`, the root filesystem. You can create a separate partition (or work LVM) and mount for example /var/lib/docker on its own partition or logical volume. By separating directories from the root filesystem your operating system stays responsive and maintainable, with LVM you're way more flexible. Maybe this helps to understand the root directory structure: https://www.howtogeek.com/117435/htg-explains-the-linux-directory-structure-explained/